# Java 8 JRE 8u111 o 8u112, cual es el mejor/correcto?

Tags: java

En la web de Oracle, se ofrecen dos versiones de Java JRE, quisiera saber cuál de los dos es el correcto a instalar para desarrollar en Eclipse Neon usando Java.

Link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

1. Java SE Runtime Environment 8u111
2. Java SE Runtime Environment 8u112

Otra cosa, en la web dice que NetBeans ya tiene JDK 8, debería de usar este en lugar de Neon?.

Comment: Evidentemente siempre debe preferir la última versión disponible, pues esta incluye las últimas actualizaciones de seguridad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El JRE incluye la maquina virtual Java para correr sus aplicaciones. EL JDK es para desarrollar e incluye el JRE.
Siempre es mejor tener la ultima version del JRE porque trae correciones de bugs.
Yo te recomendaría Java SE Runtime Environment 8u112

Comment: sobre netbeans vs eclipse neon, cual seria el correcto?.

Comment: independientemente. Podes usar Netbeans o Eclipse. Ya depende de tu gusto. Si no tenes claro cual de los dos. Instala los dos y ve cual te gusta mas.

Comment: perfecto, una ultima cosa, debería instalar JRE o el JDK para hacer programas ya sea en Eclipse o Netbeans?.

Comment: El jdk para programar. Si instalas el jdk ya te instala el jre

Answer (score 2):

Los dos son correctos, solamente que 8u112 es una versión más reciente.
En cuánto el IDE a mí me gusta más utilizar NetBeans por qué se me hace más "amigable", pero lo que dice la web es una sugerencia, si a ti te gusta más Eclipse Neon pues usalo.

Comment: En realidad el tema del IDE es muy personal. Por ejemplo, yo prefiero IntelliJ porque es realmente más práctico que Eclipse y Netbeans, pero he usado tanto tiempo Eclipse que sigo amarrado a él =P